# Why I can't install SQL SERVER 2008 R2 EXPRESS on my laptop?

Tags: windows-xp, sql-server-2008

When I try to execute SQL SERVER X86 on my laptop...it appear a message...isnt a win32 application!
What can I do?I really want to install the management studio.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a corrupted download. Download again and try it.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers,now I try to download from Microsoft the trial.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of your current setup but you might want to check the Prereq's of the software and your current running  OS. You might need to be running Windows 2008 R2 to use that software.

PS Windows Server R2 is a x64 only platform. so it will not run on win32 based systems.

Comment: I downloaded Microsoft SQL SERVER 2008 R2 ,NOT WINDOWS SERVER 2008!

Comment: That is my point you need to run SQL_server 2008 R2 ON windows 2008 R2 server OS.

Comment: No, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express runs on Servers and Clients as well. It's only a SQL-Database-Server.

Answer (score 0):

A COMPLETELY LAME FACT about Sql Server Management Studio 2008 is that it will not install on ANY version of Windows Vista or 7 that is a home edition.

Answer (score 0):

> "I really want to install the management studio."

If all you want is the Management Studio, perhaps you can just [download "Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Management Studio Express"](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b) from Microsoft?